# ImportError: cannot import name tz (psycopg2)

Tags: python, apache, postgresql, mod-wsgi, psycopg2

I am using Windows XP, and using Python run time from http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7/python-2.7.msi

If I am running in standalone application, `import psycopg2` doesn't cause me any trouble. However, when come to mod_wsgi + apache, I will get the following error

```
[Thu Nov 18 14:26:51 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=2832): Target WSGI script 'C:/Projects/SandBox/web/script/index.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Nov 18 14:26:51 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=2832): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Projects/SandBox/web/script/index.py'.
[Thu Nov 18 14:26:51 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Nov 18 14:26:51 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "C:/Projects/SandBox/web/script/index.py", line 9, in <module>
[Thu Nov 18 14:26:51 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     import psycopg2
[Thu Nov 18 14:26:51 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "build\\bdist.win32\\egg\\psycopg2\\__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
[Thu Nov 18 14:26:51 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from psycopg2 import tz
[Thu Nov 18 14:26:51 2010] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] ImportError: cannot import name tz
```

Here is the python script.

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))

import psycopg2

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

and here is the httpd.conf file.

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Projects/SandBox/web/"
<Directory "C:/Projects/SandBox/web">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I check the archive `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.2.2-py2.7-win32.egg\`, there is  `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\psycopg2-2.2.2-py2.7-win32.egg\psycopg2\tz.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that Python doesn't know your egg cache location (or doesn't have privileges to it). You just need to set that. More information **[here](http://lethain.com/entry/2009/feb/13/when-psycopg2-can-t-import-tz/)**. Try setting the [`WSGIPythonEggs`](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIPythonEggs) directive.